# Send array of string using tcp

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm not sure if this is possible but here it goes.
Usually I send strings like this...

```
Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('alpha');
Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('bravo');
Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('charley');
//and so on..
```

But what if I want to send it in just one go, just send it all at once.
Maybe I could put it on an array of strings then send the array.

```
someStr : array[1..3] of string = ('alpha','bravo','charley');//this could be more
```

...

```
StrListMem := TMemoryStream.Create;
try

   StrListMem.WriteBuffer(someStr[0], Length(someStr));
   StrListMem.Position:=0;

   Connection.IOHandler.Write(StrListMem, 0, True);

finally
   StrListMem.Free;
end;
```

I just have no idea how to this right, maybe somebody can give an example? and how the receiver(client) will read it.

**EDIT:**

I also having problem in how to read the stream, not sure what's wrong with this code.

Client:

```
msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  arrOf: Array of Char;
```

...

```
  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, False);
    SetLength(arrOf, msRecInfo.Size div SizeOf(Char));

    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
    msRecInfo.ReadBuffer(arrOf[0], Length(arrOf) * SizeOf(Char));

  finally
    MessageBox(0,pChar(arrOf[0]),0,0);//memo1.Lines.Add(arrOf[0]);
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the whole array to stream in one swoop. You actually already wrote close to a correct code

```
StrListMem := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
   for I := 0 to Length(someStr) - 1 do
   begin
     StrListMem.WriteBuffer(someStr[I][1], Length(someStr[I]) * SizeOf(Char));
     StrListMem.WriteBuffer(sLineBreak[1], Length(sLineBreak) * SizeOf(Char));
   end;

   StrListMem.Position:=0;    
   Connection.IOHandler.Write(StrListMem, 0, True);    
finally
   StrListMem.Free;
end;
```

Alternatively if you want to only work with data and abstract the transport layer away (read, easier coding) you can check out my [IMC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-imc/). It abstracts some things for you making it easier.

**EDIT:**

I added the newline character after each string as it seems to be consistent with original OP code. I don't have Delphi at hand so do not blindly copy the code please.

**EDIT:**

After reading the question again I realized that his goal is only to send it in one go and it is not mandatory to use a string array. So there is a better way to do it.

```
StrListMem := TStringList.Create;
try
  StrListMem.Add('alpha');
  StrListMem.Add('bravo');
  StrListMem.Add('charley');
  Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferOpen;
  try
    Connection.IOHandler.Write(StrListMem);    
  finally
    Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClose;
  end;
finally
  StrListMem.Free;
end;
```

To read it

```
StrListMem := TStringList.Create;
try
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStrings(StrListMem);
finally
  StrListMem.Free;
end;
```

Easier and cleaner :)

Comment: It seems like the OP wants new line after each string.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies, I know I ask to many favors, but could you also help me out on how the client will read it ? I added my Client code.

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically it is the same no matter which way you send the data.